# How to create a Cron Job to generate a report and write a SQL query for that report?

Tags: sql, linux, cron, report

i wanna generate a report and i have the SQL query ready but i was asked to use Cron Job and my knowledge is limited on it , so how can i integrate my query in the Cron expression

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

good night

Putting it in linux cron would look like this:
Run the crontab -e command at the linux prompt.

## crontab -u user -e

- Enter command to be executed
  Example:
  su - postgres -c 'psql -U user -At database_name -h ip_address -p port -c "query"'